# check if arraylist is NOT empty java

Tags: java, arraylist

I know the isEmpty() method used to check if an arraylist is empty, but I am trying to check if an arraylist is not empty. I tried to look online but I didn't find any useful information on how to do this. My code is like "while ArrayList is not empty then run code).

Comment: `while(!myList.isEmpty())`?

Comment: this should work thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invert the result of `isEmpty()`.

```
public boolean notEmpty(ArrayList a) {
    return !a.isEmpty();
}
```

That will tell you when a list is not empty.

Comment: why do a method call, when you can directly do !list.isEmpty() ?

Comment: I prefer to call it negate.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also check whether the array is null by the length/size of the arraylist.

```
while(arrayListName.size() > 0 ){
//execute code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize arrays as `null` you can just check if they are not `null`:

```
List<String> myArray = null;

myArray = myFunction.getArrayValues;

if (myArray != null) {
  processArray (myArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to read for me

```
while (arrayList.isEmpty() == false) {
  //do something cool
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be useful

```
    if (!arrayList.isEmpty() ){
            //execute code
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1));
         }
```